# I need to Split name column into first name, middle name (if available) and last name columns when reading csv into sql database

Tags: python, database, sqlite, csv, dictionary

I'm new to programming, I have a csv file i want to read into a sql database but while reading the csv file i need to split the name column into first_name, middle_name and last_name. the csv file content looks like the below:

```
name, location, birth_year
Jane Tolu Omo, Rayfield, 1979
Myles Jim Jones, London, 1980
```

so i wrote this below:

```
# Creating a dictionary to hold the different names
nameDict = {name: None for name in names}

# Creating another dictionary to full students (csv) data
studentsDict = {}

# open csv file given by command line argument, read it one line at a time
with open('characters.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        nameDict = row['name'].split()
        studentDict = (nameDict, row['house'], row['birth'])
        print(studentDict)
```

I got this below:

```
(['Harry', 'James', 'Potter'], 'Gryffindor', '1980')
(['Hermione', 'Jean', 'Granger'], 'Gryffindor', '1979')
(['Isobel', 'MacDougal'], 'Ravenclaw', '1980')
(['Justin', 'Finch-Fletchley'], 'Hufflepuff', '1979')
```

Just want to ask if i got this right and if there are any side effects or how to make it better. Thanks for your kind review

Comment: I would use pandas - then apply a function to the first column. That being said, you have the data correctly read to process how you would like. Possible errors, names are not always space separated - you have the handle this somehow (error handling)

you have a relatively big requirement to fill, what do you do when you don't have 3 elements first,middle, last name? is it assumed that middle name is optional (I assume so) but good to have it known.

Comment: Since it works, it is better to ask this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks @Chinny84, it was a long day and night, then sleep took its course :) Thanks for the detailed review. I would check out panda then. Hmm... I knew there would be a challenge if i dont have 3 names and not sure how to handle that any suggestions, assuming i stick with this or use panda?

Answer (score 0):

It's a manner, but probably you have to create the labels for new list of names to avoid unnecessary looping.If you're analyzing data, I recommends to you use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).
Pandas is more dynamic and fast to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with pandas for this kinda operation.

```
import pandas as pd
# read input csv
df = pd.read_csv('61165261-input.csv')
df[['firtname','middlename','lastname']] = df.name.str.split(expand=True)
# write updated data frame to new csv
df.to_csv('61165261-input.csv', index=False)
print(df)
```

output:

```
              name   location   birth_year   ...    firtname middlename lastname
0    Jane Tolu Omo   Rayfield         1979   ...        Jane       Tolu      Omo
1  Myles Jim Jones     London         1980   ...       Myles        Jim    Jones
```

Comment: good to show the behaviour for where there are only two names to split.

Comment: Thanks @Shakeel, it was a long day and night, then sleep took its course :) Thank you very much for this I will try it out and see.

Comment: @Shakeel, I tried this and it looks sweet, i really like it, just that where name is just two it keeps the last name in the middle name column. I will try to figure this out and show it here but you have any ideas pls drop it. thanks again.

Comment: @osedev, If I have correctly understood you want just last name and middle name column instead of name(replacing name) ?

Comment: @osedev Let me know if you were able to solve the problem with above snippet.

Comment: @Shakeel, yes it worked but where user had only 2 names the last name was being dropped in the middle name column. so I used a loop to fix that and it worked well even with a python DictReader so I blanked the pandas as comment in the code because i would need it sometime. I've posted it as the answer. see above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code lines that finally worked for me on this problem:

## Opening the CSV file

with open(argv[1], "r") as student_file:

```
# Reading the CSV file
reader = csv.DictReader(student_file)

# Loop through rows
for row in reader:
    names = row["name"].split()

    if len(names) == 2:
        first = names[0].strip()
        last = names[1].strip()
        db.execute("INSERT INTO students (first, middle, last, house, birth) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                   first, None, last, row["house"], int(row["birth"]))

    elif len(names) == 3:
        first = names[0].strip()
        middle = names[1].strip()
        last = names[2].strip()
        db.execute("INSERT INTO students (first, middle, last, house, birth) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                   first, middle, last, row["house"], int(row["birth"]))
```